# Android: PagerAdapter creating double Fragments after config change

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am currently using a custom PagerAdapter (note **not** a FragmentPagerAdapter). My problem? When I titl the smartphone for screen rotation the Activity as we all know gets destroyed then is recreated. In this notion the Fragments are stored.

My problem is that I am not using a PagerAdapter that returns Fragments(this is what FragmentPagerAdapter does). I am returning an inflated layout, as seen here.

```
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View itemView = null;
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft;

            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.left, container, false);

                leftFragment = new LeftFragment();
                ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.left, leftFragment);
                ft.commit();

                break;
            case 1:
                itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.middle, container, false);

                MiddleFragment middleFragment = new MiddleFragment();
                ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.middle, middleFragment);
                ft.commit();

                break;
            case 2:
                itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.right, container, false);

                rightFragment = new RightFragment();
                ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.right, rightFragment);
                ft.commit();

                break;
            case 3:
                itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.right_right, container, false);

                rightRightFragment = new RightRightFragment();
                ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.right_right, rightRightFragment);
                ft.commit();

                break;
            }

            ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);
            return itemView;
        }
```

What this does is that it creates a new instance of a Fragment. However the Activity already stores some of these.

This is causing onCreate() etc. to fire twice, which is not a good thing for my app (I have Threads which are created in onCreate(), this means I get 2x the amount of Threads I want casuing havoc for synchronization).

Does nyone know how to either force the Activty not to store the fragments, if not, how could one restore them properly into a custom pager adapter.

Comment: I don't know why do you store some of these fragments in the activity. Why don't you get the instances of your fragments from the adapter in the activity as well? Or on `instantiateItem()` you can update the fragment references in the activity.

Comment: Where do I get the instances from, the Bundle on onCreate?

Comment: You can update your references from `instantiateItem()`.

Comment: I don't quite understand, Everytime I rotate the device the instantiateItem creates new Fragments. How do I reference the Fragments that the Activity stores on a config change?

Comment: On your `instantiateItem()` you can call YourActivity.this.myFragment = newFragmentInstance;

Comment: That's creating a new Fragment though (... = newFragmentInstance)?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41343/discussion-between-ricardo-and-karl-morrison)

Comment: @Ricardo I thought it would only be fair to update you on the issue as you took your time to help me. My findings of the FragmentPagerAdapter is that it does the exact same thing, FragmentPagerAdapter creates double fragments on config change aswell, so I guess I wasn't doing anything wrong. I solved the issue with a slight "hack". An if condition on a static varible outside of the Fragment, works well but kinda hackish. thanks for your help man! :)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the feedback. Did you get a chance to see the code I posted? Here: https://github.com/riclage/fragmentwithinfragment Doesn't it do what you wanted?